# Is there a simple way to pass one or two np.arrays to a function without splatting an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator, args

I have a function that needs to be able to accept one or two arrays, transform them, and then return the transformed arrays

Is there an alternative to `function(*args)` that does not unpack a single Numpy array over its first dimension, or a suggested workaround?

Comment: It looks like you unpack the array in the function call, `function(array1)` should work, as well as `function(array1,  array2)` or arbitrary number of positional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using optional args:

```
def transformsinglearr(arr):
    #enter code here

def foo(arr1 = None, arr2 = None):
    arr1t = None
    arr2t = None
    if not( arr1 is None) : arr1t = transformsinglearr(arr1)
    if not( arr2 is None) : arr2t = transformsinglearr(arr2)
    result = [arr1t, arr2t]
    result = [i for i in result if i] #remove nones
    return result
```

Its much less elegant than *args but it does the same job.

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with `*args`? It plays nicely with lists/arrays without splatting.

```
def foo(*args):
    print(args)

foo([1])
foo([1], [2])

([1],)
([1], [2])
```